# Gradient Descent vs Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, gradient-descent

I tried to train a FeedForward Neural Network on the MNIST Handwritten Digits dataset (includes 60K training samples).

I each time iterated over **all the training samples**, performing **Backpropagation** for each such sample on every epoch. The runtime is of course too long.

- Is the algorithm I ran named **Gradient Descent**?

I read that for large datasets, using **Stochastic Gradient Descent** can improve the runtime dramatically.

- What should I do in order to use **Stochastic Gradient Descent**? Should I just pick the training samples randomly, performing **Backpropagation** on each randomly picked sample, instead of the epochs I currently use?

Comment: Perhaps you need to choose correctly value of the `learning rate`. More explanation of SGD can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new scenario you describe **(performing Backpropagation on each randomly picked sample)**, is one common "flavor" of Stochastic Gradient Descent, as described here: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-gradient-descent-and-stochastic-gradient-descent

The 3 most common flavors according to this document are (Your flavor is C):

A)

```
randomly shuffle samples in the training set
for one or more epochs, or until approx. cost minimum is reached:
    for training sample i:
        compute gradients and perform weight updates
```

B)

```
for one or more epochs, or until approx. cost minimum is reached:
    randomly shuffle samples in the training set
    for training sample i:
        compute gradients and perform weight updates
```

C)

```
for iterations t, or until approx. cost minimum is reached:
    draw random sample from the training set
    compute gradients and perform weight updates
```

Comment: Great, so my thought was right, I just need to randomly pick samples and train the network on them... It sounds very easy to implement

Answer (score 12):

I'll try to give you some intuition over the problem...

Initially, updates were made in what you (correctly) call **(Batch) Gradient Descent**. This assures that each update in the weights is done in the "right" direction (Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHlJE.png)): the one that minimizes the cost function.

[image: Gradient Descent]

With the growth of datasets size, and complexier computations in each step, **Stochastic Gradient Descent** came to be preferred in these cases. Here, updates to the weights are done as each sample is processed and, as such, subsequent calculations already use "improved" weights. Nonetheless, this very reason leads to it incurring in some misdirection in minimizing the error function (Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBk3p.png)).

[image]

As such, in many situations it is preferred to use **Mini-batch Gradient Descent**, combining the best of both worlds: each update to the weights is done using a small batch of the data. This way, the direction of the updates is somewhat rectified in comparison with the stochastic updates, but is updated much more regularly than in the case of the (original) **Gradient Descent**.

**[UPDATE]** As requested, I present below the pseudocode for **batch** gradient descent in binary classification:

```
error = 0

for sample in data:
    prediction = neural_network.predict(sample)
    sample_error = evaluate_error(prediction, sample["label"]) # may be as simple as 
                                                # module(prediction - sample["label"])
    error += sample_error

neural_network.backpropagate_and_update(error)
```

(In the case of multi-class labeling, error represents an array of the error for each label.)

This code is run for a given number of iterations, or while the error is above a threshold. For stochastic gradient descent, the call to *neural_network.backpropagate_and_update()* is called inside the *for* cycle, with the sample error as argument.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description!!

Comment: When you say `each update to the weights is done using a small batch of the data`, do you mean you don't run backpropagation for each sample you insert to the network?

Comment: That's right! You compute the error over that small batch, and you run backpropagation using that error (just like you do in traditional batch gradient descent). It is exactly that fact (you may think of it as somewhat of an average direction) that makes the convergence being smoother than with stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: How do you calculate the error over a whole batch? Can you add some pseudo-code? It could be helpful for many people

Comment: When running backpropagation, the outputs of the neurons in the hidden layers are essential for computing their errors. Should I aggregate (i.e. sum or average) the outputs per hidden neuron and use this aggregated value for computing the error, just like you demonstrated for the neurons in output layer?

Comment: Or should I compute all the errors in every iteration, in a backpropagation-like process, without updating any weight, and then finally make an update using all the errors I collected along all the iterations?

Comment: how do you backpropagate using just the error?
don't you need the output and target to calculate the cost derivative?

Comment: @Viliami you are right, you use the cost per example when computing the contribution of each unit in your NN during backpropagation, and sum/average contributions accross training examples to get the overall direction. The above pseudo-code is not intended to showcase that part, just to give an overall perspective. If you're using cycles like above (instead of working with matrices), the error summation would be replaced by an append to a vector.